# Есть ли максимальный размер (pxl) картинки для добавления в приложение?

Tags: android, android-imageview

Пытаюсь добавить (разными способами) в приложении картинку 3000х2000 пикселей. В "дизайнере" Андроид студии все показывается нормально, при запуске приложения - экран пустой. Использовал ImageView (как в контейнере так и через setContentView).

При уменьшенном (через фотошоп) размере - картинка показывается, но с недопустимой потерей качества.

Соответственно, вопрос. Есть какое-то ограничение на максимальный пиксельный размер jpg/png? И можно ли его как-то обойти, чтобы добавить требуемый размер?

Comment: Как вариант, можно картинку резать на куски и показывать их вместе.

Comment: да, думал об этом... а как сделать, чтобы они выглядели единым куском? чтобы свободно пальцем по нему гонять)